# Visualizing Bin packing with FF using C++

Tags: c++, visualization, bin-packing

I'm new here so I will try my best. I want to visualize the Bin packing problem in C++ using First Fit. What I want is to create an initial tournament tree (winner) with external nodes as objects with certain capacity where can I put some bins. After inserting those bins, I want to get the finaly tree.
What I've done so far:

- I've got the algorithms running properly but simple (not anything special) in dos
- I'm using VS 2015 Community and searched how to visualize binary trees with SDK but had no luck (I'm new to programming so my knowledge isn't the best)
- I've searched some other external programs to visualize my tree (yEd, Automatic graph layout and graphical binary trees (but as I checked the last two use only C# )

So here is my questions: 
Is there any other programm that I can use to visualize Bin packing problem?
Can I use those programs that I mentioned, to visualize C++ and not in C#?
If it's possible to use SDK to visualize my problem I would really need some guide, or some sort of tutorial how to use it in my case.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm a student and this is a project that I try to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **strongly** suggest that you [use Qt for this](https://www.qt.io/).

I know this will be a bit of a steep learning curve. But unfortunately there are no "native" tools from microsoft that offer the same. The microsoft SDK alone will not do. You would need something like Expression Blend. But these tools are mainly for C#.

Although there are alternatives to Qt like [Wx](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) and [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/) I suggest you try Qt. It has the following advantages:

- it's as close to C++ as it gets
- it comes with its own IDE
- it fully supports and works together with Visual Studio 2015
- it is completely free
- it's easy to install and upgrade and automatically finds a Visual Studio installation and uses it

Comment: Qt is not pure C++, it has its own macro language (similar to C++ preprocessor) and must be compiled through moc and uic.

Comment: @BenVoigt, What did Qt do against you that you write such rubbish about it? "Qt uses standard C++ with extensions including signals and slots" [according wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)). It is build in 63.9% C++ [according openhub.](https://openhub.net/p/qt5/analyses/latest/languages_summary) The rest is XML, C, JavaScript, Python etc.

Comment: So, you found additional evidence that it is not "pure C++".  I suggest you correct your answer.  (Note that I haven't gotten into my opinion about Qt, or the rather negative interaction with a Qt developer here on Stack Exchange... just the fact that [the Qt project itself proudly proclaims](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html), that it is not pure C++)

Comment: @BenVoigt are you more happy now with my answer?

Comment: @Bogdan Willi thanks for your quick answer. I checked Qt with graphiz and it's exactly what I need. Now I have to learn it.